# Determine maximum window bounds

Tags: java, swing, gui

**Preamble:** the default frame positioning with Swing `JFrame`s has always bothered me. Eventually I wrote some code to calculate my available desktop space, not counting my abnormally-large right-side-anchored taskbar, and use that information to size and position my `JFrame`s. Then I got sick of copy/pasting the same frame size calculations into every Main.java of every pet project I make. So, I spent the better part of today writing a one-class library to centralize the functionality. I'm just doing this for practice and my own twisted sense of hard-working laziness, but it is complete and functioning code.

**What I would like feedback on:** the usual best practices for Java and Swing, naming of the class/methods/parameters of the public interface, and if it's not too much trouble I would also like feedback on the Javadoc I've written, since I've never written this level of documentation for professional projects.

I published a PDF of the javadoc and uploaded it so it's not necessary to read through the markup for that. It will be available [here](http://temp-host.com/download.php?file=ml33lu) for one week.

The first thing I expect to be criticized is the name—I'm unhappy with `TlcSizer`, which was based on the initialism for *top-level container*, but `FrameSizer` was too specific and I'm not sure what would be both clear and concise.

**TlcSizer.java:**

```
package tlcsizer;

import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.GraphicsEnvironment;
import java.awt.Point;
import java.awt.Rectangle;
import java.awt.Window;
import javax.swing.LookAndFeel;
import javax.swing.UIManager;
import javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException;

/**
 * {@code TlcSizer} is a utility class for Swing user interfaces to determine
 * top-level component bounds based on screen size and available screen space.
 * <p>This class is designed so that you can acquire an instance prior to
 * initializing your interface, which minimizes the impact of changing the
 * {@link LookAndFeel}. By aquiring a sizer instance and using only
 * instance methods, you can avoid the implementation details of
 * look&nbsp;and&nbsp;feel changes.
 * <p>The static methods are made available for finer control over this
 * process, though it is usually unnecessary to use them.
 * <p><b>Note:</b> this class does not implement support for multi-screen
 * environments.
 */
public final class TlcSizer {
    private final Rectangle mwb;

    /**
     * Creates a new FrameSizer. The current {@link LookAndFeel} will be
     * altered to account for objects in the native windowing system such as
     * task bars and menu bars in calculating the available screen space. After
     * performing this calculation, the look&nbsp;and&nbsp;feel will be reset to
     * the previous look&nbsp;and&nbsp;feel.
     * <p>The {@code FrameSizer} class is designed so that you can acquire an
     * instance prior to initializing your interface, which minimizes the impact
     * of changing the look&nbsp;and&nbsp;feel. This constructor is best used
     * before client code sets the look&nbsp;and&nbsp;feel.
     * <p><b>Warning:</b> this constructor alters the current
     * look&nbsp;and&nbsp;feel. This will cause strange behaviour in your
     * application if your interface has already been initialized. If this is
     * the case, you must call {@link
     * javax.swing.SwingUtilities#updateComponentTreeUI(java.awt.Component)}
     * once for each top-level container. It is recommended that you
     * re-{@link Window#pack() pack} your top-level container after this
     * operation.
     * @throws tlcsizer.TlcSizer.TlcSizerException if there was a
     * problem setting the look&nbsp;and&nbsp;feel
     */
    public TlcSizer() throws TlcSizerException {
        this.mwb = getMaxBounds(true);
    }
    /**
     * Creates a new {@code FrameSizer}, setting the look&nbsp;and&nbsp;feel as
     * specified. This constructor needs to alter the current
     * look&nbsp;and&nbsp;feel to account for objects in the native windowing
     * system such as task bars and menu bars in calculating the available
     * screen space. After performing this calculation, the specified
     * look&nbsp;and&nbsp;feel will be set.
     * <p>The {@code FrameSizer} class is designed so that you can acquire an
     * instance prior to initializing your interface, which minimizes the impact
     * of changing the look&nbsp;and&nbsp;feel. This constructor is best used
     * as a replacement for setting the look&nbsp;and&nbsp;feel in client code.
     * <p><b>Warning:</b> this constructor alters the current
     * look&nbsp;and&nbsp;feel. This will cause strange behaviour in your
     * application if your interface has already been initialized. If this is
     * the case, you must call {@link
     * javax.swing.SwingUtilities#updateComponentTreeUI(java.awt.Component)}
     * once for each top-level container. It is recommended that you
     * re-{@link Window#pack() pack} your top-level container after this
     * operation.
     * @param lookAndFeel the name of the {@link LookAndFeel} to set
     * @throws tlcsizer.TlcSizer.TlcSizerException if there was a
     * problem setting the look&nbsp;and&nbsp;feel
     */
    public TlcSizer(String lookAndFeel) throws TlcSizerException {
        this.mwb = getMaxBounds(false);
        try {
            UIManager.setLookAndFeel(lookAndFeel);
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException | InstantiationException |
                IllegalAccessException | UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
            throw new TlcSizerException(ex);
        }
    }
    /**
     * Creates a FrameSizer which relies upon a given maximum window bounds,
     * rather than calculating it internally. This eliminates the usual need for
     * a FrameSizer to change the current look&nbsp;and&nbsp;feel to the
     * system's native look&nbsp;and&nbsp;feel to calculate the bounds itself.
     * @param maximumWindowBounds the externally-provided maximum window bounds
     */
    public TlcSizer(Rectangle maximumWindowBounds) {
        this.mwb = maximumWindowBounds;
    }

    /**
     * Calculates the bounds for a top-level container of a given size such that
     * the top-level container is centred <i>on the screen</i> as best as
     * possible. The size and position are constrained to fit within available
     * space, which excludes objects in the native windowing system such as
     * task bars and menu bars.
     * @param preferredWindowSize The preferred size of the top-level container.
     * Often, this is best obtained by {@link java.awt.Window#pack() packing}
     * it and then calling {@link java.awt.Window#getPreferredSize()}.
     * @return the bounds calculated for the given top-level container size
     * @see #getSpaceCentredBounds(java.awt.Dimension) 
     * @see #getScreenCentredBounds(java.awt.Dimension, java.awt.Rectangle) 
     * @see GraphicsEnvironment#getMaximumWindowBounds() 
     */
    public Rectangle getScreenCentredBounds(Dimension preferredWindowSize) {
        return getCentredBounds(preferredWindowSize, mwb,
                ReferenceRegion.SCREEN);
    }

    /**
     * Convenience method for setting the bounds of a window after its
     * preferred, centred bounds have been determined. The window will be
     * packed, which comes with the side-effect of setting it displayable.
     * @param window the window whose bounds are to be set
     * @return {@code true} if the window's bounds were changed as a result of
     * this operation
     * @see #getScreenCentredBounds(java.awt.Dimension) 
     * @see Window#pack() 
     */
    public boolean setScreenCentredBounds(Window window) {
        return setBounds(window, mwb, ReferenceRegion.SCREEN);
    }

    /**
     * Calculates the bounds for a top-level container of a given size such that
     * the top-level container is centred <i>on the screen</i> as best as
     * possible. The size and position are constrained to fit within available
     * space, which excludes objects in the native windowing system such as
     * task bars and menu bars.
     * @param preferredWindowSize The preferred size of the top-level container.
     * Often, this is best obtained by {@link java.awt.Window#pack() packing}
     * it and then calling {@link java.awt.Window#getPreferredSize()}.
     * @param maximumWindowBounds The maximum window bounds for the screen,
     * usually obtained from {@link #getMaxBounds(boolean)}.
     * @return the bounds calculated for the given top-level container size
     * @see #getSpaceCentredBounds(java.awt.Dimension, java.awt.Rectangle) 
     * @see #getScreenCentredBounds(java.awt.Dimension)
     * @see GraphicsEnvironment#getMaximumWindowBounds() 
     */
    public static Rectangle getScreenCentredBounds(
            Dimension preferredWindowSize, Rectangle maximumWindowBounds) {
        return getCentredBounds(preferredWindowSize, maximumWindowBounds,
                ReferenceRegion.SCREEN);
    }

    /**
     * Convenience method for setting the bounds of a window after its
     * preferred, centred bounds have been determined. The window will be
     * packed, which comes with the side-effect of setting it displayable.
     * @param window the window whose bounds are to be set
     * @param maximumWindowBounds The maximum window bounds for the screen,
     * usually obtained from {@link #getMaxBounds(boolean)}.
     * @return {@code true} if the window's bounds were changed as a result of
     * this operation
     * @see #getScreenCentredBounds(java.awt.Dimension) 
     * @see Window#pack() 
     */
    public static boolean setScreenCentredBounds(Window window,
            Rectangle maximumWindowBounds) {
        return setBounds(window, maximumWindowBounds, ReferenceRegion.SCREEN);
    }

    /**
     * Calculates the bounds for a top-level container of a given size such that
     * the top-level container is centred <i>within the available space</i> as
     * best as possible. These bounds account for objects in the native
     * windowing system such as task bars and menu bars.
     * @param preferredWindowSize The preferred size of the top-level container.
     * Often, this is best obtained by {@link java.awt.Window#pack() packing}
     * it and then calling {@link java.awt.Window#getPreferredSize()}.
     * @return the bounds calculated for the given top-level container size
     * @see #getScreenCentredBounds(java.awt.Dimension) 
     * @see #getSpaceCentredBounds(java.awt.Dimension, java.awt.Rectangle) 
     * @see GraphicsEnvironment#getMaximumWindowBounds() 
     */
    public Rectangle getSpaceCentredBounds(Dimension preferredWindowSize) {
        return getCentredBounds(preferredWindowSize, mwb,
                ReferenceRegion.AVAILABLE_SPACE);
    }

    /**
     * Convenience method for setting the bounds of a window after its
     * preferred, centred bounds have been determined. The window will be
     * packed, which comes with the side-effect of setting it displayable.
     * @param window the window whose bounds are to be set
     * @return {@code true} if the window's bounds were changed as a result of
     * this operation
     * @see #getSpaceCentredBounds(java.awt.Dimension) 
     * @see Window#pack() 
     */
    public boolean setSpaceCentredBounds(Window window) {
        return setBounds(window, mwb, ReferenceRegion.AVAILABLE_SPACE);
    }

    /**
     * Calculates the bounds for a top-level container of a given size such that
     * the top-level container is centred <i>within the available space</i> as
     * best as possible. These bounds account for objects in the native
     * windowing system such as task bars and menu bars.
     * @param preferredWindowSize The preferred size of the top-level container.
     * Often, this is best obtained by {@link java.awt.Window#pack() packing}
     * it and then calling {@link java.awt.Window#getPreferredSize()}.
     * @param maximumWindowBounds The maximum window bounds for the screen,
     * usually obtained from {@link #getMaxBounds(boolean)}.
     * @return the bounds calculated for the given top-level container size
     * @see #getScreenCentredBounds(java.awt.Dimension, java.awt.Rectangle) 
     * @see #getSpaceCentredBounds(java.awt.Dimension) 
     */
    public static Rectangle getSpaceCentredBounds(
            Dimension preferredWindowSize, Rectangle maximumWindowBounds) {
        return getCentredBounds(preferredWindowSize, maximumWindowBounds,
                ReferenceRegion.AVAILABLE_SPACE);
    }

    /**
     * Convenience method for setting the bounds of a window after its
     * preferred, centred bounds have been determined. The window will be
     * packed, which comes with the side-effect of setting it displayable.
     * @param window the window whose bounds are to be set
     * @param maximumWindowBounds The maximum window bounds for the screen,
     * usually obtained from {@link #getMaxBounds(boolean)}.
     * @return {@code true} if the window's bounds were changed as a result of
     * this operation
     * @see #getSpaceCentredBounds(java.awt.Dimension) 
     * @see Window#pack() 
     */
    public static boolean setSpaceCentredBounds(Window window,
            Rectangle maximumWindowBounds) {
        return setBounds(window, maximumWindowBounds,
                ReferenceRegion.AVAILABLE_SPACE);
    }

    private static boolean setBounds(Window window, Rectangle mwb,
            ReferenceRegion region) {
        window.pack();
        final Rectangle newBounds = getCentredBounds(window.getPreferredSize(),
                mwb, region);
        final boolean wasTlcModified = newBounds.equals(window.getBounds());
        if (wasTlcModified) {
            window.setBounds(newBounds);
        }
        return wasTlcModified;
    }

    private static Rectangle getCentredBounds(Dimension preferredSize,
            Rectangle mwb, ReferenceRegion region) {
        final Rectangle newBounds;
        final Dimension dFrame = new Dimension(
                Math.min(mwb.width, preferredSize.width),
                Math.min(mwb.height, preferredSize.height));
        final Point pFrame = new Point();
        final int x;
        final int y;
        switch (region) {
            case SCREEN:
                final Dimension screen =
                        java.awt.Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize();
                // calculate ideal position
                x = (screen.width - dFrame.width) / 2;
                y = (screen.height - dFrame.height) / 2;
                // constrain position to avoid clipping OS desktop decorations
                pFrame.x = constrain(x, mwb.x, mwb.x + mwb.width);
                pFrame.y = constrain(y, mwb.y, mwb.y + mwb.height);
                break;
            case AVAILABLE_SPACE:
                x = mwb.x + (mwb.width - dFrame.width) / 2;
                y = mwb.y + (mwb.height - dFrame.height) / 2;
                // unnecessary to constrain since we used mwb for ideal position
                assert x == constrain(x, mwb.x, mwb.x + mwb.width);
                assert y == constrain(y, mwb.y, mwb.y + mwb.height);
                break;
            default:
                throw new RuntimeException("switch enum hit default case");
        }
        return new Rectangle(pFrame, dFrame);
    }

    private static int constrain(int value, int min, int max) {
        if (max < min) throw new ArithmeticException();
        value = Math.min(value, max);
        value = Math.max(value, min);
        return value;
    }

    /**
     * This method obtains the maximum window bounds from the local
     * {@link GraphicsEnvironment} via
     * {@link GraphicsEnvironment#getMaximumWindowBounds()
     * getMaximumWindowBounds()}. This method changes the
     * look&nbsp;and&nbsp;feel to the native system look&nbsp;and&nbsp;feel,
     * which is necessary for an accurate result.
     * @param changeLnfBackAfterwards whether to change the
     * look&nbsp;and&nbsp;feel back to the previously set
     * look&nbsp;and&nbsp;feel after the maximum bounds have been obtained.
     * @return the maximum bounds
     * @throws tlcsizer.TlcSizer.TlcSizerException if there was a
     * problem setting the look&nbsp;and&nbsp;feel
     */
    public static Rectangle getMaxBounds(boolean changeLnfBackAfterwards)
            throws TlcSizerException {
        LookAndFeel originalLnf = UIManager.getLookAndFeel();
        try {
            UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException | InstantiationException |
                IllegalAccessException | UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
            throw new TlcSizerException(ex);
        }
        // Needs to be done with the platform-dependent look and feel active
        Rectangle mwb = GraphicsEnvironment.getLocalGraphicsEnvironment()
                .getMaximumWindowBounds();
        if (changeLnfBackAfterwards) {
            try {
                UIManager.setLookAndFeel(originalLnf);
            } catch (UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
                throw new TlcSizerException(ex);
            }
        }
        return mwb;
    }

    private static enum ReferenceRegion { SCREEN, AVAILABLE_SPACE }

    /**
     * Thrown when a {@link TlcSizer} encounters an exception when attempting
     * to set the look&nbsp;and&nbsp;feel. The cause is set to the original
     * exception encountered, which may be any of those thrown by
     * {@link UIManager#setLookAndFeel(java.lang.String)}.
     * @see Exception#getCause()
     */
    public final static class TlcSizerException extends Exception {
        private TlcSizerException(Throwable cause) { super(cause); }
    }
}
```

Comment: Wells, +1 for comments on `public` methods, it will be nicer for developers/maintainers if you do the same for your `private` ones too. :)

Comment: @h.j.k. That's a good point. I have a tendency to get lazy with private and/or internal names; rolfl points out a similar sentiment in the opening paragraph of [his answer](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/61150/51897). I will work on breaking this habit.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### General

Your variable names are not helpful enough. I understand that `mwb` is `maximum window bounds`, but it is still too short.

In general, I worry that you have too many different ways to access the core logic. Too many public methods.

Further, some of your methods require a `TlcSizer` instance, but others are just public static methods. This inconsistency is confusing.

On the other hand, the JavaDoc is neat and consistent. I like the detail you have (but I am a lots-of-detail-person, I know other people who will think you have overdone it). I can tell you have paid attention to paragraphs, and other formatting in the JavaDoc.

Out of interest, when you have a `<p>` in the JavaDoc, I suggest also adding an empty line to make it a paragraph in the code format too, and also have an empty line before the `@param` sections. For example, your JavaDoc:

> ```
> /**
>  * Creates a new {@code FrameSizer}, setting the look&nbsp;and&nbsp;feel as
>  * specified. This constructor needs to alter the current
>  * look&nbsp;and&nbsp;feel to account for objects in the native windowing
>  * system such as task bars and menu bars in calculating the available
>  * screen space. After performing this calculation, the specified
>  * look&nbsp;and&nbsp;feel will be set.
>  * <p>The {@code FrameSizer} class is designed so that you can acquire an
>  * instance prior to initializing your interface, which minimizes the impact
>  * of changing the look&nbsp;and&nbsp;feel. This constructor is best used
>  * as a replacement for setting the look&nbsp;and&nbsp;feel in client code.
>  * <p><b>Warning:</b> this constructor alters the current
>  * look&nbsp;and&nbsp;feel. This will cause strange behaviour in your
>  * application if your interface has already been initialized. If this is
>  * the case, you must call {@link
>  * javax.swing.SwingUtilities#updateComponentTreeUI(java.awt.Component)}
>  * once for each top-level container. It is recommended that you
>  * re-{@link Window#pack() pack} your top-level container after this
>  * operation.
>  * @param lookAndFeel the name of the {@link LookAndFeel} to set
>  * @throws tlcsizer.TlcSizer.TlcSizerException if there was a
>  * problem setting the look&nbsp;and&nbsp;feel
>  */
> ```

would be better if written:

```
/**
 * Creates a new {@code FrameSizer}, setting the look&nbsp;and&nbsp;feel as
 * specified. This constructor needs to alter the current
 * look&nbsp;and&nbsp;feel to account for objects in the native windowing
 * system such as task bars and menu bars in calculating the available
 * screen space. After performing this calculation, the specified
 * look&nbsp;and&nbsp;feel will be set.
 * <p>
 * The {@code FrameSizer} class is designed so that you can acquire an
 * instance prior to initializing your interface, which minimizes the impact
 * of changing the look&nbsp;and&nbsp;feel. This constructor is best used
 * as a replacement for setting the look&nbsp;and&nbsp;feel in client code.
 * <p>
 * <b>Warning:</b> this constructor alters the current
 * look&nbsp;and&nbsp;feel. This will cause strange behaviour in your
 * application if your interface has already been initialized. If this is
 * the case, you must call {@link
 * javax.swing.SwingUtilities#updateComponentTreeUI(java.awt.Component)}
 * once for each top-level container. It is recommended that you
 * re-{@link Window#pack() pack} your top-level container after this
 * operation.
 * 
 * @param lookAndFeel the name of the {@link LookAndFeel} to set
 * @throws tlcsizer.TlcSizer.TlcSizerException if there was a
 * problem setting the look&nbsp;and&nbsp;feel
 */
```

### Bugs

In this method I believe you have a bug:

> ```
> private static boolean setBounds(Window window, Rectangle mwb,
>         ReferenceRegion region) {
>     window.pack();
>     final Rectangle newBounds = getCentredBounds(window.getPreferredSize(),
>             mwb, region);
>     final boolean wasTlcModified = newBounds.equals(window.getBounds());
>     if (wasTlcModified) {
>         window.setBounds(newBounds);
>     }
>     return wasTlcModified;
> }
> ```

The boolean `wasTlcModified` should be the *negated* value of `newBounds.equals(window.getBounds())`.

A second bug, in `private static Rectangle getCentredBounds(Dimension, Rectangle, ReferenceRegion)`, you have the option of `AVAILABLE_SPACE` as the region. From what I can see, that option does nothing. It sets the values of the `x` and `y` variables, but then does nothing with those values. What is the point?

### Style

1-liners (even simple ones) should have `{}` braces:

> ```
> if (max < min) throw new ArithmeticException();
> ```

should be:

```
if (max < min) {
    throw new ArithmeticException();
}
```

Additionally, adding a useful message would be good:

```
if (max < min) {
    throw new ArithmeticException(String.format(
        "Specified min value %d is larger than the specified max value %d", min, max));
}
```

Actually, if it was me, I would just remove the check since I have full control over the code, and I can't see how the condition is violated. But, you have `assert` statements in other places so I am not sure why you don't just assert this condition too. Consistency is always important. Hmm, while looking at the method, it may as well just be:

```
private static int constrain(int value, int min, int max) {
    return Math.max(Math.min(value, max), min);
}
```

Your TlcException is.... unnecessary. You may as well just declare that your method throws a plain `Exception`. If it was me, I would at least make the `TlcException` a `RuntimeException` so there are not checked exceptions coming out.

Further, the constructor does not take a message, and is all on one line... ouch:

> ```
> private TlcSizerException(Throwable cause) { super(cause); }
> ```

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to review my code. I'll do my best to learn from it. Though the StackExchange format doesn't really encourage it, I hope I'm not being *too* unconventional by responding in depth:

Comment: **General #2/3:** "In general, I worry that you have too many different ways to access the core logic... Further, some of your methods require a `TlcSizer` instance, but others are just public static methods. This inconsistency is confusing." This was something I felt somewhat wishywashy about. In the spirit of your comment, I will use the static getters, chop out the static setters, and eliminate the instantiables altogether. This makes #1 (member variable name unhelpful) a moot point, but a point taken nonetheless.

Comment: **General #4/5:** Thanks for the positive feedback on my Javadoc. It feels dirty to ask for feedback on something I am proud of, but it's easy to start second-guessing oneself when nobody else is seeing one's work. I also hear what you've said about a preference for details, and absences thereof. I like your newline tips, too, and I think I will incorporate them into my style.

Comment: **Bugs:** Yes, you are correct on both counts. The former is as simple as you point out. The latter error is my forgetting to assign those values to pFrame because of a sloppy copy/paste/modify. My only tested use-case never explored the `AVAILABLE_SPACE` case, or I would have seen that the method was returning a `Rectangle` originating at (0,0) regardless of input.

Comment: **Style:** On one-liners, I agree. Further laziness on my part, though I believe in the reasons for avoiding such blockless `if` statements, per [Steve McConnell](http://www.stevemcconnell.com/cc.htm). As far as throwing exceptions and using assertions goes, this is something I've never really been comfortable with. Where is the line between too much error-checking and too little? I have a vague idea, since I cross it both ways frequently...

Comment: **The TlcException:** This was a case of my wanting to pass checked exceptions up the stack, but also wanting to hide away the ugliness that is a four-class multicatch. Netbeans warned me away from using too broad a catch when I tried simply catching them as `Exception`, but it doesn't seem to mind my declaring `throws Exception`. I can't see a solution that I like; perhaps I will ask about this at Programmers.